# node wkhtmltopdf create corrupted PDF in node webkit

Tags: node.js, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, node-webkit

Im having a lot of trouble in node webkit to convert html to PDF. 
Im using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1 and did the npm install wkhtmltopdf. 
Here is my node code:

```
    var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');
    var fs = require("fs-plus");

   // URL
   wkhtmltopdf('http://google.com/', { pageSize: 'letter' })
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.pdf'));
```

It gave me an error. Later I found this https://github.com/devongovett/node-wkhtmltopdf/pull/9 
I did the correcting and im not getting any error anymore but the PDF that I get in return is **corrupted**.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have found a solution. I instead use https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js with phantomJS and run this from node-webkit with phantomJS and it work like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried following the examples on the [node-wkhtmltopdf page](https://github.com/devongovett/node-wkhtmltopdf).

First example generates a corrupted pdf file.

```
// URL
wkhtmltopdf('http://google.com/', { pageSize: 'letter' })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.pdf'));
```

Though, this example works fine on my end.

```
wkhtmltopdf('http://google.com/', {output: 'out.pdf'});
```

You can also provide html instead of a url.

That being said, I am unable to generate a pdf within a node-webkit application. There doesn't seem to be any error, but nothing happens either.

Testing on Windows 7 64 bits.

I'd be curious to know why nothing is happening in a node-webkit application.

Comment: For me the wkhtmltopdf('http://google.com/', {output: 'out.pdf'}); still dosen't work. Maybe because im on win 8.