# PDF generation with PhantomJS in node-Webkit

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs, node-webkit

I found a comment in this subject [node wkhtmltopdf create corrupted PDF in node webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224155/node-wkhtmltopdf-create-corrupted-pdf-in-node-webkit) which indicates that it's possible to generate pdf from html in node-webkit by using PhantomJS and especially with this script:  https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js

However I don't understand how to use this script without command line call...

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use the script as-is directly in node.js. You would either use the [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module to call phantomjs essentially as a commandline script with the `rasterize.js` script and options.

The other possibility is to use a phantom wrapper for node.js to directly include the code of `rasterize.js`. You would need to make only small adjustments like the `page` argument is passed from the wrapper and does not need to be created. Possible wrappers are [node-phantom](https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom) or [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node). If you package your app with node-webkit, then you will probably run into problems with the path to the phantomjs executable.

Answer (score 0):

Phantomjs' Rasterize.js worked well to generate clean multi-page editable pdf's conserving all the tricky CSS. I got a little confused when trying to use it within a nodejs environment but its pretty straight forward.

As per [NPM Phantomjs readme:](https://www.npmjs.org/package/phantomjs) (I've stated it a little more explicitly)

```
var path = require('path')
var childProcess = require('child_process')
var phantomjs = require('phantomjs')
var binPath = phantomjs.path

//Args for rasterize.js: [ rasterize.js URL filename [paperwidth*paperheight|paperformat] [zoom]') ]

var childArgs = [ path.join(__dirname, 'rasterize.js'),'url','docname.pdf','A4',1.00]

childProcess.execFile(binPath, childArgs, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  // handle results
})
```